# Schema.org for multiple product dependencies or pre-requisites

Tags: schema.org

In Schema.org I can use the [`addOn`](https://schema.org/addOn) property to indicate if a product offering can only be obtained in combination with another offer or product.  However, I am not sure how I can represent "AND" vs "OR" relationships.

I want to be able to show different relationships between products. For example, in order to purchase Product A, the customer must purchase Product B or Product  C.  Or, in order to purchase Product D the customer must purchase Product E and Product F.